# Information on Microsoft.Graph.Teams.Channel via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, microsoft-teams

Does anyone have any experience using the Microsoft.Graph.Teams.Channel module for PowerShell and what commandlets are available?

Comment: Could you please share more context with what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to be able to Get user activity from a Teams group or channel such as teams user logins, and messages and so on via PowerShell. I already have the Microsoft Teams Module.

Comment: Can you check if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0